# MySQL server at localhost>:3306[root](disconnected) >nodeUnable to register mysql server 5.6 in Netbeans 8.1

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I am creating a web database app project for the first time, and I get this:

[image: netbeans image]

When I right click on MySQL server at `localhost>:3306[root](disconnected) >node` in services window in net beans and click connect and  I get this ,when i right click MySQL server at `localhost>:3306[root](disconnected) >node`inside service window and click start

[image: net beans]

When I right click , the node jdbc:mysql;//localhost;3306/MyNewDatabase[root on default schema]under the drivers in service window and click  connect it connects without any problem.[drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCVON.jpg) Please help me. I am unable to register mysql server 5.6 on Netbeans 8.1. I have even tried adding adding mysql libraries to the project but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer the problem is with my drivers i remove all of the drivers and add mysql conector java 5.1.13.jar i found it around removing the driver[add driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71rJM.jpg),now i can easily connect